# How to Convert CYYMM to YYYY-MM

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have some date columns that are formatted as CYYMM (e.g. 12012). I would like to convert these to a typical data representation in SQL Server.

FYI. C stands for century.

E.g. 12012 should be 2020-12 (for December of 2020)

Another

11210 should be 2012-10 (for October of 2012).

How could I go about accomplishing this efficiently and 1900-safe. For example I have accomplished doing it like :

```
declare @dte int = 12012;
select '20' + left(substring(cast(@dte as char(5)), 2, 5),2) + '-' + right(@dte,2)
```

But I would like to know if there is a more native solution that doesn't rely on hard coding the '20'.

Comment: If C is for century, why isn't it 212012? We're in the 21st century, not the 1st century.

Comment: @Larnu This was a Y2K hack.... Century Indicator.   0 was assumed to be 19  and 1 would be 20

Comment: Yuck... I honestly wonder where the person with the sense of "we should use 4 digits for the year" was during that meeting, and why they weren't invited... It also makes me wonder how they would deal with dates prior to 1900-01-01 `-19812` for December of 1898? >_<

Comment: @AaronBertrand well you guys have mostly covered it in the comments a 1900 example would be 09912 for 1999-12

Comment: Ahh, so like the 2 digit cut off in SQL Server might be 2049, @AaronBertrand , so `01/02/48` would be 2048 and never 1948, and likewise `03/04/50` would be 1950 and never 2050.

Comment: Guys!  You're over thinking it.   It was a short-term patch for the mainframes during Y2K.   Back then, every byte counted.

Comment: We might be, but the problem is that it's something the for OP to explain, @JohnCappelletti . I, personally, had never seen this kind of notation, and if this is something that could come up in the future for other users, then knowing that `0`/`1` simply is a `1900+`/`2000+` (rather than perhaps a `1850+`/`1950+`) identifier will be important to them.

Comment: @Larnu That's all it was ... a simple flag.    We just had to get through the day and keep the planes in the sky, pumps pumping and ATMs online.

Comment: @Larnu I am working in a legacy system and nobody understands the actual origin of what these fields represent. I do not know the origin or the exact logic of how it is derived but I am told it is a Century identifier.

Comment: I'm in my 50's and have never heard of this format. If I remember correctly on the old HP3000 machines I worked on storage was aligned on word boundaries, if so 12012 would use the same storage as 202012.

Comment: This is utilizing a very old IBM tool. A full date would be something like 1201205 which would represent 2020-12-05 and we have to perform logic like ```try_convert(date,cast((@Date)+19000000 as char(8)),101)```. Its not ideal, I know but I wanted to know what I can do to handle things that just have 12012 which is year-month format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming first character would be 1 or 0

```
declare @dte int = 02012;

Select left((@dte/10000+19),2)+stuff(right(@dte,4),3,0,'-')
```

**Results**

```
1920-12
```

Comment: I suppose one could reasonably assume that the value would need to be stored in a string based data type? Otherwise `02012` would be stored as `2012`, not `'02012'`.